# Does .NET have the history of time zone changes?

Tags: .net, datetime, timezone

Our government loves to change local time or enable|disable daylight saving time.

MS deployed patch for Russia to take new time change into account.

Now there is the question whether history of the changes exists?

When I get UTC time of the day in 01.01.2000 system should remember that Moscow time zone had +3 UTC.  (in summer +4) at that moment.

For 01.01.2012 we had +4 UTC for both winter and summer. And soon we will have +3 UTC.

simple test shows that .NET does not keep records about the changes:

```
var t = new DateTime(2012,1,1);
// UTC +4 expected
System.Console.WriteLine(t.ToLocalTime());
// UTC +4 expected
t = new DateTime(2012,06,1);
System.Console.WriteLine(t.ToLocalTime());
// UTC +3 expected
t = new DateTime(2000,1,1);
System.Console.WriteLine(t.ToLocalTime());
// UTC +4 expected
t = new DateTime(2000,6,1);
System.Console.WriteLine(t.ToLocalTime());
```

Does some additional API exist to cope with the problem?

**Update:**

Have found class [TimeZoneInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo(v=vs.110).aspx) and related [AdjustmentRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.adjustmentrule(v=vs.110).aspx) class. Left to test whether customization of `TimeZoneInfo.Local` time zone  affects DateTime APIs.

**Update 2:**
Seems like UTC offsets are not stored as history and `AdjustmentRule` changes only daylight time during the year.

Comment: Take a look at `DateTimeOffset`. ***If*** you can capture the timezone offset as you capture the data you will be in better shape to display it and calculate against it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

.NET tracks *some* history, but it is not always accurate.  You've stumbled upon one of the inaccuracies.

.NET imports all of it's time zone information from Windows via the registry, as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bclteam/archive/2007/06/07/exploring-windows-time-zones-with-system-timezoneinfo-josh-free.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724253.aspx).  If you look in the registry at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Time Zones\Russian Standard Time\Dynamic DST` you'll find that it only tracks information from 2010 forward for this time zone.  Testing dates in year 2000 is not going to work well, as it will fall back to the earliest rule available (2010).

Base UTC offset information *is* tracked in the registry, but *not* in the `AdjustmentRule` class that .NET imports it into.  If you check the adjustment rules for this time zone, you'll find that 2012 and 2013 are not imported at all:

```
var tz = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Russian Standard Time");
foreach (var rule in tz.GetAdjustmentRules())
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0:d} - {1:d}", rule.DateStart, rule.DateEnd);
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
1/1/0001 - 12/31/2010
1/1/2011 - 12/31/2011
1/1/2014 - 12/31/2014
```

Even though they exist in the Windows registry, 2012 and 2013 are not imported because they have no daylight saving time adjustments.

This creates a problem when the base offset changes - like it has for this time zone.  Since it is currently +3, and the two year where it was +4 were not imported, then it will look like it was +3 for those missing years.

There is no good solution for this using `TimeZoneInfo`.  Even if you try to create your own custom time zones, you'll have trouble fitting this kind of change into the data structures available.

Fortunately, there is another option.  You can use standard [IANA time zones](http://www.iana.org/time-zones), via the [Noda Time](http://nodatime.org/) library.

The following code uses Noda Time to match what you wrote in your original code:

```
DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb.GetSystemDefault();
Console.WriteLine(Instant.FromUtc(2012, 1, 1, 0, 0).InZone(tz).LocalDateTime);
Console.WriteLine(Instant.FromUtc(2012, 6, 1, 0, 0).InZone(tz).LocalDateTime);
Console.WriteLine(Instant.FromUtc(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0).InZone(tz).LocalDateTime);
Console.WriteLine(Instant.FromUtc(2000, 6, 1, 0, 0).InZone(tz).LocalDateTime);
```

If your local time zone is not already set for Moscow, you can change the first line to:

```
DateTimeZone tz = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["Europe/Moscow"];
```

OUTPUT:

```
1/1/2012 4:00:00 AM
6/1/2012 4:00:00 AM
1/1/2000 3:00:00 AM
6/1/2000 4:00:00 AM
```

## Update

The problem described above of `AdjustmentRule` not tracking base offset changes was described in Microsoft Support article [KB3012229](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3012229), and subsequently fixed in .NET Framework 4.6 and also in .NET Core.

In [the reference sources](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timezoneinfo.cs,742c8a401f7fb010), one can see that `AdjustmentRule` now keeps a `m_baseUtcOffsetDelta` field.  While this field is not exposed via a public property, it does factor in to the calculations, and it does reflect in serialization if you use the `FromSerializedString` and `ToSerializedString` methods (if anyone actually uses those).

Comment: Something has changed a couple of days ago. Now 2012 and 2013 are imported. At least in .NET 4.5.2 (Win8.1, Win10)

1/1/0001 - 12/31/2010
1/1/2011 - 12/31/2011
1/1/2012 - 12/31/2012
1/1/2013 - 12/31/2013
1/1/2014 - 12/31/2014

But where is the data for 2015 and 2016?

Comment: The last Russia change in 2014 dropped daylight saving time, so there are no adjustment rules for 2015 and later because there are no adjustments; the offset is fixed.  The last offset of the last rule in the list should always apply from that time forward.

Comment: Also, though you're targeting 4.5.2, I'll guess you have 4.6 installed on the box so it's using the fix for [KB3012229](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3012229) that was implemented in 4.6 (the KB still needs to be updated to reflect that).  The side effect is that you now see transition rules for 2012 and 2013 because it's now tracking base-offset changes correctly.

Comment: Lastly, be aware that there are [new time zone changes coming to Russia this month](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/russia-astrakhan-time-zone.html).  The Russian government has still not finalized all of them, and provided a very short notice effective date (grrr...).  That means it's uncertain to whether they'll be a Windows update or hotfix in time to get in front of it, as Microsoft must wait for the government to make up their mind.

Comment: I added an update to the answer describing the changes. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you can try NodaTime,

http://nodatime.org/

better explanation of what is does

http://blog.nodatime.org/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html

Comment: Noda Time - Yes, but link-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Historical time zone data is very complex and filled with many examples of small exceptions that apply in specific geographical regions that today have no easy way of being described. Not only are the offsets changing, but so are the regions to which they are applied.

There is a project to model the history of this data from around the world here:

- http://www.iana.org/time-zones
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tz_database

.NET doesn't support what you want out of the box. Making a general solution to the problem will be very difficult, however if you only need it over a small set of regions, then you should be able to populate this yourself using the [`TimeZoneInfo` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), the documentation for which states:

> The members of the TimeZoneInfo class support the following operations:
>
> - Creating a new time zone that is not already defined by the operating system