# Conversion from UTC to Timezone time produces different result with 4.0 and 3.5 SP1

Tags: .net, timezone

We keep all times in our database as UTC. Based on the client's location the UTC time gets converted to a local time using .net function

```
 public static DateTime ConvertToLocalTime(DateTime utcTime, string timezoneId)
 {
        try
        {
            return TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeBySystemTimeZoneId(utcTime, TimeZoneInfo.Utc.StandardName, timezoneId);
        }
        catch
        {
            return new DateTime();
        }
}
```

There was a problem reported that some reports have produced wrong results in DateTime fields, and when I started looking at it deeper, I realized that the same above code called form SQL2008 (compiled with .net 3.5) produces different result if called from the client application compiled with .net 4.0. The result is incorrect in 3.5 and correct in 4.0 for Chile timezone for year 2015 when DST was observed the whole year.

I can assume that this might have been a missing hotfix specifically produced for .net 3.5 and currently missing. But if anyone previously came across this or similar problem, I would appreciate some extra input.

Answer (score 1):

A few things first:

- Don't use `StandardName` when you mean `Id`.  While they may match in some cases, that is not guaranteed.  Especially, consider that `StandardName` (along with `DaylightName` and `DisplayName`) are localized based on the OS's primary language.  They will look quite different on a Japanese PC than on an English one.
- The `Id` for UTC is simply `"UTC"` - so you could hardcode that if you like.  Alternatively, use `TimeZoneInfo.Utc.Id`, or preferably switch to the `TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTimeFromUtc` method.
- The try/catch here is going to mask any real exceptions, such as a `TimeZoneNotFoundException` if the `timeZoneId` passed is not valid.

Now with regard to differences between releases, the behavior you're experiencing is the one described in [KB3012229](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3012229).  While the article mentions Russian time zones, it is also applicable for the recent time zones changes in Chile.  It occurs because the `TimeZoneInfo.AdjustmentRule` class was originally designed without considering that the base offset from UTC can also change from year-to-year.  This was fixed in .NET 4.6, by the addition of an internal property `BaseUtcOffsetDelta`, which [you can see in the reference sources here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/timezoneinfo.cs,601f39fc2d5538af).

If you have .NET 4.6 or greater installed on the machine, then any application using the the .NET 4 runtime (that is, any app targeting .NET 4.0 or greater) will have the corrected implementation and work properly.  (This is also fixed in .NET Core.)

From testing on my own machine, it also appears to be fixed in .NET 3.5, however I'm not sure which particular update resolved the problem.  Make sure you've installed all updates, and the problem should (probably) go away.

[Some more on this here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26166892/634824).

Comment: Thanks for pointing to a bug in the code and the detailed background information, using StandardName is definitely wrong. I will try the updates and hopefully will catch the missing one.