# DateTime IsDaylightSavingTime() backwards compatibility

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

EU has countries which will give up using separate time on summer and winter. This can happen [as soon as 2021](https://ec.europa.eu/transport/themes/summertime_en).

Will `System.DateTime` handle this issue with backwards compatibility? Does it know when DST has been in use and when not?

```
// When running in 'FLE Standard Time' on 2023: false (obviously)
var isDayLightSavingTime = new DateTime(2023, 5, 1).IsDaylightSavingTime();

// When running in 'FLE Standard Time' on 2023: true (?)
isDayLightSavingTime = new DateTime(2019, 5, 1).IsDaylightSavingTime();
```

Comment: What is your local time zone?

Comment: @SonerGönül FLE Standard Time

Comment: This uses `TimeZoneInfo`, which gets its knowledge from the registry (on Windows). So as long as Windows is updated with the new timezone information (which it will be), .NET will pick up on this. Windows knows about historical changes to daylight savings. During World War 2, for example, the UK went into double daylight savings (+2).

Comment: @canton7 Cool. Ok then this will not be problem at all -  thanks for sharing..

Comment: Actually, I don't think I'm entirely accurate - some historical rules are imported, and some aren't. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156260/does-net-have-the-history-of-time-zone-changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`IsDaylightSavingTime` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.isdaylightsavingtime?view=netframework-4.7.2) returns the specific `DateTime` is within the daylight saving time range of the local time zone, which is returned by [`TimeZoneInfo.Local`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timezoneinfo.local?view=netframework-4.7.2) property.

If this method returns `true` for `DateTime(2019, 5, 1)`, that means it is in DST time in your local time zone which all these data saved in the registry. Since you mentioned it is FLE Standard Time (which refers [Eastern European Time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_European_Time) in generally), in 2019, DST started March 31st and ended October 27th. That's why May 1st will be in DST time in that time zone.

> Will System.DateTime handle this issue with backwards compatibility?

Probably. But this "giving up" is not certain for now as far I can see on that post. When it will be certain, I'm quite sure that Microsoft will release a data update (since it will be a huge update) as fast as they can and they announce in their [time zone blog](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Daylight-Saving-Time-Time-Zone/bg-p/DSTBlog).

In such a case, it is important to keep your operating system updated.

Comment: Good info package thanks! I'm less worried now when knowing that DST changes are quite regular issue around the globe..I think my colleagues will be googling this issue later on when government makes actual decision on DST change schedule (our industry deals with a lot of time series data..)